# A complicated syntax over preprocessor in C

Tags: c, stdout, stdin, stderr

I am trying to figure out code in C and I am stuck at trying to understand what the part of preprocessor actually does. The part of code I do not understand is following:

```
#define ERR(source) (perror(source),\
         fprintf(stderr,"%s:%d\n",__FILE__,__LINE__),\
         exit(EXIT_FAILURE))
```

whole code is very short, and looks as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ERR(source) (perror(source),\
             fprintf(stderr,"%s:%d\n",__FILE__,__LINE__),\
             exit(EXIT_FAILURE))

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    char name[22];
    scanf("%21s",name);
    if(strlen(name)>20) ERR("Name too long");
    printf("Hello %s\n",name);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: So which part of this macro are you having trouble understanding?

Comment: all the macro I do not understand. I am very novice in C. I do not know what is ERR, then the next part (perror(source.... ) then I do not know why there is backslash, then __FILE__,__LINE__ is hard for me to understand

Comment: `ERR` is the name of the macro (this is what the code is defining), `perror`, `fprintf` and all the other things are part of the C standard libraries, you can find their definitions online. And the backslash simply means the macro definition continues on the next line (so you don't have to cramp everything into a single line)

Comment: @hegendroffer: `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` are macro's that will expand to the current file/translation unit, and the current line number. As a quick [goolge search would've told you](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Standard-Predefined-Macros.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The backslash in the macro means you can read the next line as if it is one line, so it boils down to this:

```
 #define ERR(source) (perror(source), fprintf(stderr,"s:%d\n",__FILE__,__LINE__), exit(EXIT_FAILURE))
```

A `#define` preprocessor statement is used to replace code with other code, for example

```
#define SOMECONSTANT 5
```

will replace `SOMECONSTANT` in your code with `5`, before compiling the code. The preprocessor also understands function-like syntax, which is what you have here.

Your macro results in the following main body:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    char name[22];
    scanf("%21s",name);
    if(strlen(name)>20) (perror("Name too long"), fprintf(stderr,"s:%d\n",__FILE__,__LINE__), exit(EXIT_FAILURE));
    printf("Hello %s\n",name);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The macro in your case uses the comma-operator to put a few statements together, so you can use it as one statement. Usually, your code would be written as:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    char name[22];
    scanf("%21s",name);
    if(strlen(name)>20) {
          perror("Name too long");
          fprintf(stderr,"s:%d\n",__FILE__,__LINE__);
          exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("Hello %s\n",name);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Hopefully you understand what is going on now.

Comment: Thank you, I understood everything :)